# Implementing custom dialog with different options(which will use intent)

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to implement custom dialog in which I have to dial a number inside the custom dialog for which I am suing intent but its not working application is force closing every time.

Also the method I am using for custom dialog is showing deprecated. If anyone can suggest alternate way for custom dialog

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6;
EditText et1;
ImageButton ib1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ib1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(1);

        }
    });

}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{

    Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this);
    switch (id) {
        case 1:
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.call);
            ib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    String num = et1.getText().toString();
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:"+num);
                    dial.setData(uri);
                }
            });

            break;
    }
    dialog.show();
    return dialog;
}
}
```

Logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: bt4u.com.intentdemo1, PID: 15895
                                                                  Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.rr.neptune, iconPack:system, fontPkg:com.rr.neptune, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.rr.neptune, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.rr.neptune}
                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at bt4u.com.intentdemo1.MainActivity.onCreateDialog(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:3348)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:1074)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3442)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:3400)
                                                                      at bt4u.com.intentdemo1.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21156)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="bt4u.com.intentdemo1.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Make A Call"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send A Text"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Open Website"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Google Search"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Send An Email"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="39dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

call.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/call"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:onClick="call"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: force close?? It means your app crashed with an exception. Post logcat stacktrace

Comment: added logcat report

Comment: do you have Imagebutton `ib` in your layout of dialog? Post the layout which you're setting to your dialog

Comment: updated with both the xml file

Comment: imagebutton is not ib. ib is the reference of thee image button

Answer (score 0):

The NullpointerException is because you're trying to get the `ImageButton` from your main activity xml, but the ImageButton is in your `call.xml`.

So it should be

```
 case 1:
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.call);
//Initialize your ImageButton here. Do the same for your EditText as well.
        ImageButton ib1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        EditText et1 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText); //INITIALIZE EDITTEXT HERE.
        ib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                String num = et1.getText().toString();
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:"+num);
                dial.setData(uri);
            }
        });

        break;
```

This should work

Comment: but if i use with edittext. it says i have to make it final

Comment: I did same what you said it still showing force close

Comment: '                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference'

Comment: @SripadRaj Is correct The `ImageButton` is defined in the `call.xml` but you are trying to find it from your `main.xml`.
Your `EditText` needs to be declared final as you are invoking some of it's methods from an anonymous class (`new View.OnClickListener() {...`)

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method call(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'imageButton'

Comment: remove `android:onClick="call"` in your xml.

Comment: I already did everything that you asked to do and still its not working. It is showing this ------ java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: I have already written in the code that `EditText` should also be inflated in the dialog. Put this `EditText et1 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText)` after ImageButton initialization.

Comment: As I said I have done everything that you asked including imagebutton, edittext and removing onclick.. Its showing null pointer exception

Comment: I HAVE UPDATED THE CODE. IF YOU STILL GET NULL POINTER EXCEPTION, POST THE NEW LOGCAT!!!